# Connecting to OpenVPN server using iOS 13.3 does not work as it used to

Tags: ios, iphone, openvpn

I have iOS ver. 13.3 installed on my iPhone X. I also have an OpenVPN server configured at home that can be reached from the Internet. I also have the latest OpenVPN Connect app installed on my iPhone. When I open OpenVPN Connect application and click on the profile, I connect within a 2-3 seconds. This is all fine.

However, if I go to iPhone settings > VPN and change the status switch, the status immediately shows up as green (connected), even though it is not connected. When I open OpenVPN connect app, I see that it's trying to connect, but it fails. If I again request connection from within the app, it will connect properly.

This hasn't been like this before. The iOS VPN switch used to work. I have a feeling that it changed around iOS ver. 12, but I am not sure.

Has anyone else experienced this problem or has an idea how I can debug it/solve it?

Comment: Hi I have ovpn file, how can I use it for my iOS vpn app?

Comment: import it using OpenVPN application. If you e.g. mail it to yourself (not secure), then you can click on ovpn file and use "Open with OpenVPN". Once done it will import your profile.

Comment: Not a solution, but yes I have the *exact* same issues here with a brand new OpenVPN configuration.   everything works 100% as I'd expect with the OpenVPN application, but the iOS Settings App 'vpn' button doesn't work at all.

Looking at the server logs, there appears to be no attempt to connect at all.

Comment: @Earlyflash: Yes, I think something must have changed with the iOS update. Now the question is whether updating the OpenVPN app would solve the isse or this is something that Apple must address.

Comment: There are some interesting hints in the client FAQ: https://openvpn.net/vpn-server-resources/faq-regarding-openvpn-connect-ios/ specifically: “ Can OpenVPN profiles be connected from the Settings App? A: Yes, starting with iOS 8. Note that, if you are using 1.2.5 or older, only autologin profiles (i.e. profiles that don't require credential entry) can be launched using this mechanism. Starting with version 1.2.6, also profiles using a PKCS#12 bundle stored in the iOS keychain can be connected from the Settings.” So maybe the server needs to be configured for auto-login somehow.

Comment: @BartmanEH, it is configured for auto-login. When I open OpenVPN app on my phone I just click on the profile and I get connected. Unfortunately, if I do the same from the Settings App, it shows as it is immediately connected, but obviously it is not.